# Can I call the HERE CalculateMatrix API with interim waypoints?

Tags: rest, api, here-api

i am currently testing outh the HERE CalculateMatrix API. My goal is to get all possible routes and find out the shortest one. Now im asking myself the following question:

Is it possible to define interim waypoints that an Route has to pass? 
And is it possible that the order that these waypoints are passed is not defined?

So that i have for example the starting point: A, interim points: B and C an the destination: D,
and the Matrix should then calculate the following possible Routes:

A-B-C-D,
A-C-B-D

so im not using different destinations but different waypoints in between

Comment: Are you saying that given waypoints B and C, you want the API to calculate all routes possible where you go through either B or C first? And I'm assuming it would scale up so if you had 4 points you would do all possible combinations?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. As far as I know, there's no way to do this unless you manually generate the 'path' logic, ie: A, B, C, D and A, C, B, D. It's a math type thing you'd have to do and then pass those to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raymond already mentioned in comments, it is not possible to use Calculate Matrix API for a use case of "sortable" way-points. The Fleet Telematics API does provide something close, although it would only provide the most optimal route and not all possible routes. In the API, some way-points can be marked as "sort" which means their order is not fixed and the API would then find the most optimal route.

From API reference (https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/waypoint-sort-pickup-opening-times.html)

> Sorting Waypoints (Travelling Salesman Problem) Routing can find the
>   optimal sequence order for the waypoints. Activate this feature by
>   following waypoint parameters:
>
> &waypoint1=...;sort
>
> All sections of waypoints flagged with "sort" can be rearranged by the
>   router for cost optimization. For example, in the waypoint list of
>   WP0, WP1;sort, WP2;sort, WP3;sort, WP4, WP5;sort, WP6;sort, WP7 the
>   router can change the sequence order among WP1, WP2 and WP3, and it
>   can change the sequence order among WP5 and WP6. If the last waypoint
>   is "sort"able then the route may end at any of the sortable waypoints.
>   Use this if the driver does his overnight stay simply at/after the
>   last waypoint he visited throughout the day.
>
> &waypoint1=...;before:3,5
>
> Enforces that the route meets waypoint 1 before the waypoints 3 and 5.
>   Use it in combination with either "sort" or "optional".
>
> &waypoint1=...;implies:4,8
>
> Enforces that if waypoint 1 is part of the route then also waypoints 4
>   and 8 must be part of the route. Use it in combination with "optional"
>   waypoints.